# Send Html in .Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to get html (in Browser) at this line IN "Startup" class .but not showing it as plain text only .
ON local host https://localhost:44378/ (application default)

Its in .net core 2.2

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        //send html here  but shows simple text
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("htmls here <br>");
    });
}
```

Comment: *"but not working"* is not a technical description of a problem. In fact its not a description of anything. Please do go to great lengths to describe what is happening, what you expect and why you expect it

Comment: Why do you want to send HTML in the Startup class? And more importantly, to who do you want to send the HTML to?

Comment: @Michael Randall It shows simple text as it is

Comment: @MindSwipe  i am new was just trying.. tried many approaches

Comment: @MindSwipe: The code isnt sending html in Startup, `.Run` configures a middleware which responds (in specific case) to every request. kunal: You need set the correct content-type headers.

Comment: @Tseng  Thanks it worked

Comment: @kunalverma you need to do `context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/html");` you can't set the Headers Collection

Comment: @MindSwipe Thanks it worked

Comment: Headers is a collection, just set it via indexer. `context.Response.Headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html";` I suggest you first try with the basics (ASP.NET Core MVC/WebApi) before jumping in to the more complicated stuff. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2 as ASP.NET Core comes with a powerful templating engine (Razor) which is more powerful then trying to compose HTML yourself in code :P

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy fix, so easy [@Tseng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/455493/tseng) pointed it out in the comments: You need to set the Response's `Content-Type` header to `text/html`, this is how you could do it:

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    // Or you could use indexer like so: context.Response.Headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/html");
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("htmls here <br>");
});
```